# How to get CiviCRM root via PHP?

Tags: php

I'm working on an extension and I need to include a PHP file that is in the civicrm module root dir. Is there a way to get this directory through PHP? I need it to work for all CMS, not just Drupal.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer in the docs here: https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/framework/filesystem/#tip-programmatic-lookup_1

You can use the following:

```
Civi::paths()->getPath("[civicrm.root]/.")
```

or

```
global $civicrm_root;
```